# Storing a vector of vectors of type int in a Redis cache

Tags: c++, redis, redis-cluster

I'm using the `redis-plus-plus` C++ redis client to store data in a redis cache and I would like to know how to store an `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` object.

From the provided examples in the [git repository](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) there isn't a similar example. If there is another C++ client that can simplify the storage and retrieval of such a data structure may you also suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways.

You could serialize this and store a big string.

You could use lists. For the double-nesting thing, you'd have to get clever with the keys.

What I would do would depend on how I have to access it. But you'll have to code it yourself, somehow.

Comment: Thanks. Serializing is a better option. Option 2 won't work because during some computation i generate n! (where n >= 3 && n <= 20) number of permutations of int arrays that are required by the next process so instead of re-generating all these perms I want to store this data. The key is n.